# Looking for a way to get the current date represented as a numbered month with decimals

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, text-formatting, google-sheets-dates

Essentially I'm hoping to find a formula that would return the current date as a month in decimal form. So if it's October 15th, the number returned would be 10.48. September 10th would come back as 9.33.

I'm looking for this because I'm hoping to have the year's current sales presented as a monthly average without only dealing with completed months. If you have another way to do that, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask]. Have you already look at the list of Google Sheets functions? The Help menu includes an option that take you directly to that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 TEXT(MONTH(A2:A)+(DAY(A2:A)/DAY(EOMONTH(A2:A, 0))), "0.00")*1, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! I needed to play with the cell reference to get it to work. I changed (A2:A) to (A2) and it started working. I then realized though that the results I thought I wanted weren't going to work since today's year-to-date sales only represent 5.07, not 6.07, so I just added -1 in between the closing parenthesis and now I'm getting the results I need.